# Prove by induction $n= qb+r$ for $ n\ge 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

This is a problem given in Tom Apostol's Calculus Vol. 1
Let $b$ be a fixed positive integer.  Prove the following by induction for  all $ n\ge 0$: There exists $q$ and $r$ $\{q,r : q,r \in \mathbb{Q} , q,r > 0 \}$ such that $$n= qb+r $$  $$0 \le r < b $$

These are some assumptions I have made, but I am unable to solve the problem.
$ q \ge 0 $, $b>0$ and  $qb \ge 0 $. Also $r \ge 0$ therefore $n= qb+r\ge 0$. Now I have to prove this for a particular solution where $n \ge 1$. Then assuming this true for particular solution where $n$ is $k$  I have to prove this for $k+1$,but I have no idea how to do this. It would be of great help if someone could assist me

Comment: The question is unclear. Which of p,q,b are given and which do we need to find to make the equality hold?

Comment: b is fixed integer also i think q an r fixed nonnegative integers

Comment: for n the equality must hold

Comment: If all three are fixed, qb+r is constant so it can only hold for one value of n.

Comment: yes, sorry $0 \le r < b $

Comment: q is any nonnegative integer

Comment: If we can choose q, but not any of b or r, we still can't solve it.

Comment: I think that he means to prove Euclidean division by induction, i.e. for $b$ fixed, $\forall \space n \geq 1 \exists q r$ such that $n=qb+r$ (in which case a proof by induction is not recommended and maybe even impossible, since induction is additive and additivity does not play nice with division). Not all statements that deoend on some natural $n$ are easily provable by induction.

Comment: but b is fixed and r between o an b , nevertheless i demonstrated that is true that $  n\ge 0$ however i didnt prove by induction

Comment: the exercise tell me to prove by inductioon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $n=0$. The equation  $0=0\cdot b+0$ holds true ,so $r=0<b$ and the proposition holds true.
Suppose for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $n=qb+r,0\leq r<b$
Then $n+1=qb+r+1$ with $1\leq r+1<b+1$
If $r\leq b-2$ then $r'=r+1<b$.
If $r=b-1$ then $r'=r+1=b$ which means that actually $r'=0$
So $n+1=(q+1)b+0=q'b+r', 0\leq r'<b$.
In both cases the proposition holds true for $n+1$.

Comment: thanks for your answer . i  just don't understand r`=0, can you explain why?

Comment: if r`=0 then r=-1 and this contradicts $r\ge 0$